# Use of owsbrows.js , core.js in sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, javascript, item

I would like to know how `viewproperties` menu works an item in a list.

I googled for sometime and found that the javascript files `owsbrows.js` and `core.js` at 
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033`
will help in getting the properties of the item.

Could someone explained me how these two javascript files really works?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I think right now your question is too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wondering how the javascript is working in the background I would recommend downloading [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and examining the javascript using those tools.

Using the [javascript debugger and profiler](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) in firebug you can add breakpoints to javascript and step through it line by line.

Comment: Responding to your mod flag... your answer is about the best you can do for this sort of question and I think @KitMenke deleted it by mistake. However the question was closed because it is so broad, which means it will soon be deleted (once the user has been given some time to improve it).

Comment: Woops sorry! I didn't mean to delete your answer.

Comment: All is forgiven :)